# How to create menu like ex pander WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

How to create menu like below

[image]

i'm unable to achieve using expandar

```
my code
```

my code is below , it need work like a expandar should in right side like menu , menu still showing popup

```
<StackPanel Margin="5 0 0 0">
    <Menu  Background="Transparent">
        <Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <MenuItem Header="Peformance analysis">
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            <MenuItem Header="i.Emirates Performance" />
            <MenuItem Header="ii.Emirates Performance Trend" />
            <MenuItem Header="iii.Organizations Performance" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Incident analysis">
            <MenuItem Header="i.Incidents Frequency" />
            <MenuItem Header="ii.Incidents Frequency Trend" />
            <MenuItem Header="iii.Incident Types Frequency" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="KPI'S">
            <MenuItem Header="i.Incident Types Analysis" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="GRIDS">
            <MenuItem Header="i.Incidents History" />
            <MenuItem Header="ii.Performance Summary" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="MAPS">
            <MenuItem Header="i.Incidents Map" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: post some code (your attempt) in your question, otherwise your question will be closed